# How to return an exit code from a Powershell script only when run non-interactively

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of scripts that are running as scheduled tasks. So they do a `$host.setshouldexit(1)` on any failure, which shows up in the task scheduler as the return code.

I also want to be able to run these scripts interactively while debugging and testing. So the `$host.setshouldexit()` kills my powershell or ISE session.

My question is: how can I detect if a script is running non-interactively? If it is, then I'll use `setshouldexit`, otherwise it will print the error code or something nondestructive. (Note that I don't want to use `[environment]::userinteractive` because these scripts are not always running in what the OS thinks is a non-interactive session.)

There is a -noninteractive switch that I'm using for the scheduled tasks. Is there some way I can query that from powershell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$Host.SetShouldExit` method should not be necessary, and is actually inconsistent, depending on how you are calling your scripts. Using the keyword `exit` should get you your exit status.

Using `powershell -F script.ps1`:

- `exit` - works
- `SetShouldExit` - ignored

Using `powershell -c '.\script.ps1'`:

- `exit` - status reduced to 0 or 1, for success or failure of the script, respectively.
- `SetShouldExit` - exits with correct status, but remaining lines in script are still run.

Using `powershell -c '.\script.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE'` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18412496/265487)]:

- `exit` - works
- `SetShouldExit` - exits with status == 0, and remaining lines in script are still run.

Calling directly from powershell (`> .\script.ps1`):

- `exit` - works
- `SetShouldExit` - terminates calling powershell host with given exit status

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have it take a parameter "testing" which sets the right behavior during your tests? You have a history buffer so it will be hardly any more typing to run.

Comment: Hmm, that's not so bad. I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  The following works for me:

```
# Exit with Return Code when NOT using PowerShell ISE
if ($psise -eq $Null)
{
    $host.SetShouldExit(1)
}
```

Comment: There are more shells than the ISE that are interactive.

Answer (score 2):

Upon finding your question I have taken the issue a bit further and found `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name`.  This is False in both the command interpreter and the ISE command interpreter.  And when a script (mine is `jest.ps1`) containing just the line: `Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` is run from cmd.exe call to powershell.exe as:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -NoExit -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File "M:\WindowsPowerShell\Jest.ps1"
```

Output is simply:

> Jest.ps1

Comment: And, BTW, thank-you for the example of using $host.SetShouldExit(1)!

Comment: Inline code is marked up with backticks (`), Code blocks are marked up by indenting each line with 4 spaces. Please see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Check $Host.Name.  If your script is running outside of an IDE, it will return a value of `ConsoleHost`.  Otherwise it will return a reference to the IDE such as `Windows PowerShell ISE Host` or `PowerGUIScriptEditorHost`.

I have to use `SetShouldExit` because the scheduler that runs my scripts usually ignores other methods of indicating a failure.  I add a function to allow `SetShouldExit` when `$Host.Name` is `ConsoleHost`.  It saves a lot of IDE crashes during testing.

Comment: When a script runs as a job, $Host.Name equals "ServerRemoteHost" (tested on PS v5).

Answer (score 0):

This directly answers the question poster had about whether or not you can query if the powershell console was launched with -NonInteractive switch.

```
Function Test-IsPowerShellConsoleNonInteractive { [Boolean]([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() -Match '-NonInteractive') }
$IsPSConsoleNonInteractive = Test-IsPowerShellConsoleNonInteractive
If ($IsPSConsoleNonInteractive) { $Host.SetShouldExit(2) }
```