# -command's exit code is not the same as a script's exit code

Tags: powershell, exit-code

I need to run a script with PowerShell -Command "& scriptname", and I would really like it if the exit code I got back from PowerShell was the same as the exit code the script itself returned.  Unfortunately, PowerShell returns 0 if the script returns 0, and 1 if the script returns any non-zero value as illustrated below:

```
PS C:\test> cat foo.ps1
exit 42
PS C:\test> ./foo.ps1
PS C:\test> echo $lastexitcode
42
PS C:\test> powershell -Command "exit 42"
PS C:\test> echo $lastexitcode
42
PS C:\test> powershell -Command "& ./foo.ps1"
PS C:\test> echo $lastexitcode
1
PS C:\test>
```

Using [Environment]::Exit(42) almost works:

```
PS C:\test> cat .\baz.ps1
[Environment]::Exit(42)
PS C:\test> powershell -Command "& ./baz.ps1"
PS C:\test> echo $lastexitcode
42
PS C:\test>
```

Except that when the script is run interactively, it exits the whole shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you want to exit with `exit $lastexitcode` in your `-command` script

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you look at the part you are sending to `-Command` as a script you will see it would never work. The script running the `foo.ps1` script does not have a call to exit, so it does not return an exit code.

If you do return an exit code it will do what you want. Also change it from `"` to `'`, otherwise `$lastexitcode` will be resolved before you 'send' the string to the second PowerShell, if you run it from PowerShell.

```
PS C:\test> powershell -Command './foo.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE'
PS C:\test> echo $lastexitcode
42
```

PS: Also check out the `-File` parameter if you just want to run a script. But also know it does not `return 1` if you have a terminating error as `-Command` does. See [here](https://joshua.poehls.me/powershell-script-module-boilerplate/) for more on that last topic.

```
PS C:\test> powershell -File './foo.ps1'
PS C:\test> echo $lastexitcode
42
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This nearly solves my problem.  This solution works on the command line, which was how the problem was originally posed, so I'll accept the answer.  Unfortunately, I'm actually firing off a powershell processs from a java process using Runtime.exec, and no matter how I quote it, I'm getting an exit code of zero.  I've also tried escaping the $ on $lastexitcode with a backtick (`), and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried using -File instead of -Command like in my second example?

Comment: Using -File won't work without some other surgery because we use the same code to kick off non-powershell processes.  It looks like the quoting is getting mangled by the Java code which tries to automatically quote things as needed.  I think it should work once I sort that out.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

CAVEAT: If your PowerShell script returns exitcodes HIGHER THAN 65535, they roll over:

```
$exitCode = 65536
Exit $exitCode
```

If the following CMD calls this PS1 script above, your will get an %errorlevel% of **0**

```
Powershell.exe "& 'MyPowershellScript.ps1' "; exit $LASTEXITCODE
SET ERR=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

and an exitcode of 65537 would give you an %errorlevel% of 1, etc.

Meanwhile, if a CMD calls another and the child script returns an errorlevel higher than 65535, it passes through just fine.

```
Cmd /c exit 86666
```

The CMD Will return an %errorlevel% of 86666 as expected.

**CAVEAT to all of this: Now this is happening on and off for no apparent reason.**

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling your script interactively?

I have tried this and it seems to work OK, but I call it from DOS prompt, not within PowerShell

```
C:\Temp>type foo.ps1
exit 42


C:\Temp>powershell -noprofile -nologo -noninteractive -executionpolicy Bypass -file .\foo.ps1

C:\Temp>echo %errorlevel%
42

c:\Temp>
```

Comment: It works because you use -File instead of -Command as in the question