# Jenkins always SUCCESS state when the Shell script actually failed

Tags: shell, jenkins

I'm facing this challenge in my current Jenkins setup. Where the set of cases like Shell(bash) script executed remotely:

1. Permission denied while my installer copied
2. Unable to connect with SSH

Any suggestion on these cases how can I fix it? any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must exit your bash script with exit 1. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845381/do-manual-build-fail-in-jenkins-using-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline will fail if a script / software returns a value not equal zero. There are programs like Robocopy that execute a command, fail and return a 0. Jenkins does not understand that the program was not successful and marks the pipeline as a success.

Basically this is what you have to do. If your script returns a value not equal zero the pipeline will fail.